# Renaming an existing file with Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I've seen this question asked a few times but I have been unable thus far to achieve success using any of the post solutions. What I am trying to do is rename a file in the local storage of an app (also kind of new to Obj-c). I am able to retrieve the old path and create the new path, but what would I have to write in order to actually change the files name?

What I have thus far is:

```
- (void) setPDFName:(NSString*)name{
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* initPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[dirPaths objectAtIndex:0], @"newPDF.pdf"];
    NSString *newPath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                          [initPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent], name]
                         stringByAppendingPathExtension:[initPath pathExtension]];
}
```

Comment: So you want to rename `newPDF.pdf` in the `Documents` directory to whatever is passed into that method?

Comment: Correct! Looking to do just that.

Comment: xcode is an IDE only . I was actually irritaed by the title&tag and thought at first that you wanted to rename/refactor the method name setPDFName.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:initPath toPath:newPath error:&error];
```

Answer (score 12):

The code is very messy; try this:

```
- (BOOL)renameFileFrom:(NSString*)oldName to:(NSString *)newName
{
    NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *oldPath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:oldName];
    NSString *newPath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:newName];

    NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fileMan moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to move '%@' to '%@': %@", oldPath, newPath, [error localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

and call this using:

```
if (![self renameFileFrom:@"oldName.pdf" to:@"newName.pdf])
{
    // Something went wrong
}
```

Better still, put the `renameFileFrom:to:` method into a utility class and make it a class method so it can be called from anywhere in your project.

Comment: Why is the advice bad? Also this wouldn't suite a category as it assumes the files to be renamed are in the Documents directory, which is counter-intuitive for a category, and better suited to a class at project-scope.

Comment: Actually this contains good advice: `stringByAppendingPathComponent` is better than using `stringWithFormat` for building paths.

Comment: I guess so ^^ it is never personal but yes... you are right.. BUT here it wasnt and I did write that :) the start bugged me! [anyway, Ill then not down vote]

Comment: Everything bugs you.  There is no issue with thread-safety as long as it is understood by the caller.  Most of my methods ignore thread safety as it's largely not an issue until I explicitly do multi-threading.

Comment: Actually I don't see any threading issue here. From the documentation: "The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely." As long as you don't use a file manager *delegate* for callbacks, there should be no problem.

Comment: the opening "The code is very messy; try this:" bugged me because I found it unfriendly... I stated it. the advice is a matter of taste, ok, I shouldn't bother with that, I removed my vote